# how to solve the error on this code?

Tags: java, arrays

why there is error on the array part?
how to solve the error on the array sort?
is there any thing i need to import?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class sorting {
  public static void main(String as[])
  {
    int[] num = { 7, 4, 5, 9 };
    int l = num.length;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < l; i++) {
      System.out.println(" " + num[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Ascending order");
    Arrays.sort(num);

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      System.out.println("" + num[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Where does it occur? What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: maybe pointless... but it's a good practice to start a class with a capital letter (Sorting instead of sorting)!

Comment: What error? there is no syntax error in your code!

Comment: -1 for doing no research effort. I mean, how hard is it to look up the online Java API and find that Arrays lies in java.util?

Answer (score 4):

instead of

> import javax.swing.*

use

```
import java.util.Arrays
```

Also your first for loop should be `for (i = 0; i < l; i++)` instead of `i = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any of swing package classes. You need to import Arrays.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sort an array in ascending order
in the first for loop you are printing the original array but you are starting from index number 1 so the first array element is being skipped

change the first for loop to

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
```

and the overall program looks great

The correct one is here

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sorting {
  public static void main(String as[])
  {
    int[] num = { 7, 4, 5, 9 };
    int l = num.length;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      System.out.println(" " + num[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Ascending order");
    Arrays.sort(num);

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      System.out.println("" + num[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import `Arrays` instead of `Swing.*`